# Autocomplete doesn't work with PHP Array , SQL Datas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

Recently I have been trying to make an auto-complete search. 
I looked up some infos and figured out that there is a way to 
use PHP variables at the source... but however when I try to get a 
list of the places name, I get the results into an array

```
 $db = new OBJ_mysql($config_budapest);
 $places = array();
 //- getting the list of the cities 
 $autocomplete= $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT Helyseg FROM M_munka  WHERE Publikus = '1' AND Aktiv = 1 AND Jovahagyott = 1");
 $autocomp_q= $autocomplete->fetchAllArray();
 $writeauto = json_encode($autocomp_q); /* ECHO ALL THE RESULTS */

//array push 
  array_push($places,$autocomp_q);
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableClients = [<?php echo json_encode($places);?> ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableClients,
    });
});
</script>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Updated Result:

[image: Updated Result]

Comment: php generally doesn't run on the client

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your code, $places is an array of your query result. It seems you are creating an array of arrays (array with other arrays inside it)

Did you try to assign the query result to $places, something like this:

```
  $db = new OBJ_mysql($config_budapest);

  //- getting the list of the cities 
  $autocomplete= $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT Helyseg FROM M_munka  WHERE Publikus = '1' AND Aktiv = 1 AND Jovahagyott = 1");
  $autocomp_q= $autocomplete->fetchAllArray();
  $writeauto = json_encode($autocomp_q); /* ECHO ALL THE RESULTS */

  $places = $autocomp_q;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: wait , whats going on with the $writeauto variable ?